navigator.mediaDevices mobile multi-back cameras choosing camera without focus
In general, this implementation is working, but on some devices like the iPhone 15 Plus and Samsung S21 FE, even when choosing the correct camera, it doesn't focus properly unless zoom is applied.
What is the best approach for these cases?
sandbox: https://codesandbox.io/p/devbox/stupefied-cherry-xn67qf?file=%2Fapp%2Fpage.tsx%3A54%2C43
"use client";
import { useEffect, useRef, useState } from "react";

export default function Home() {
  const videoRef = useRef<any>(null);
  const [selectedCameraId, setSelectedCameraId] = useState<any>();

  const requestCameraPermission = async () => {
    try {
      const stream = await navigator.mediaDevices.getUserMedia({ video: true });
      const tracks = stream.getTracks();

      for (const track of tracks) {
        track.stop();
      }

      selectDefaultCamera();
    } catch (error) {
      console.log("Usuário não deu permissão na câmera");
    }
  };

  const selectDefaultCamera = async () => {
    try {
      const devices = await navigator.mediaDevices.enumerateDevices();

      const videoDevices = devices.filter(
        (device) => device.kind === "videoinput"
      );

      const devicesCompletedInfo: any = [];

      for (const device of videoDevices) {
        const stream = await navigator.mediaDevices.getUserMedia({
          video: { deviceId: { exact: device.deviceId } },
        });

        const track = stream.getVideoTracks()[0];
        const capabilities: any = track.getCapabilities();

        devicesCompletedInfo.push({ capabilities, basicInfo: device });

        track.stop();
      }

      const findCameraWithTorch = devicesCompletedInfo.find(
        (device: any) =>
          device.capabilities.torch &&
          device.capabilities.facingMode.includes("environment") &&
          !device.basicInfo.label.toLowerCase().includes("angular") &&
          !device.basicInfo.label.toLowerCase().includes("wide")
      );

      const cameraId = findCameraWithTorch
        ? findCameraWithTorch.basicInfo.deviceId
        : undefined;
      startVideo(cameraId);
    } catch (error) {
      console.log(error);
      alert("Não foi possivel listar todas cameras");
    }
  };

  const startVideo = async (cameraId: string) => {
    try {
      const constraints: any = {
        video: {
          facingMode: "environment",
          audio: false,
          width: { min: 640, ideal: 1280, max: 1920 },
          height: { min: 480, ideal: 720, max: 1080 },
          deviceId: cameraId ? { exact: cameraId } : undefined,
        },
      };

      if (videoRef.current) {
        const stream = await navigator.mediaDevices.getUserMedia(constraints);
        const track = stream.getVideoTracks()[0];
        const capabilities: any = track.getCapabilities();

        setSelectedCameraId(capabilities.deviceId);

        videoRef.current.srcObject = stream;
      }
    } catch (err) {
      console.error("Error accessing webcam: ", err);
    }
  };

  useEffect(() => {
    requestCameraPermission();
  }, []);

  return (
    <div>
      <video ref={videoRef} autoPlay playsInline />
    </div>
  );
}

